# button to close a tab showing game results works only for the first entry shown, after selecting another entry it stops working, is there a hack?

Tags: forms, firefox, onclick, submit

After opening a new tab, a php script shows the latest entry of a datebase full of game results. These are monthly events, the user can choose the event by year and month.
At the end is a button to close this tab. It works, but only if no other event/entry is selected than the first one shown. After selecting any other event, the button stops working.

`<form name="#" method="post">`
...
`<label>year: <select name="turnierJahr" id="turnierJahr" onchange='this.form.submit()'>...</select></label>`
...
`<label>month: <select name="turnierMonat" id="turnierMonat" onchange='this.form.submit()'>...</select></label>`
`<noscript><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /></noscript>`

Everything works just fine, but there at the end is aformentioned button
`<button class="grossText" type="button" value="schliessen" onclick="self.close()>`

which work if no other date than the first shown is selected.

I read about that Firefox (and Chrome) won't have a script close a tab which it not has opended by itself by default, yet I don't understand the ownership of this tab obviously or how to adress this. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: So what is actually opening the new tab here? `target` attribute on the form, which you left out, a `window.open` call - or what?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close: _"This method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the Window.open() method, or on top-level windows that have a single history entry."_ - if your second form submission is targeting that same tab again, then it will have more than one history entry afterwards.

Comment: thank you CBroe. The new tab is opened like this `<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='./Jassarchiv.php' method='post' target='_blank' accept_charset='UTF-8'>
<button type="submit" class=""> Archiv </button> 
   </form>`  Yes, the form loses the single history entry, so this is it.

Comment: _"Is there a way to make it work?"_ - only if you _don't_ cause any more history entries after the initial one, I suppose - meaning, you would have to do any loading of further records in this new tab via AJAX in the background, instead of actually submitting a form again.